# What size CD/DVD do I need to burn Ubuntu on?

Tags: installation

How large of a CD or DVD do I need in order to burn the installation ISO onto either? I currently have a Memorex CD-R, which is 700 MB, but it is apparently too small. I'm wanting to get Ubuntu 13.10. Does the CD have to have to save space as the size of the original ISO?

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 will only fit on a DVD.  You can also create a bootable USB.  See http://askubuntu.com/questions/303083/does-the-ubuntu-13-04-disk-image-fit-on-a-cd/303086#303086

Comment: Please also note that some folks measure space in powers of two, where 1M = 2^13 = 1,048,576.  Other folks measure space in powers of 10 where 1 MiB = 1,000,000... and marketing folks who can't count without taking their shoes off confuse the two. Therefore, sometimes a distro which is larger than 700,000,000 bytes really will fit on a CD-R.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to burn the Ubuntu .iso file on a single layer DVD which is typically 4.3gb in size, although it will not use the entire DVD, only around 1gb worth...  Other distributions will vary (Kubuntu, Xubuntu, Lubuntu)...

Note: Burn the .iso file at the slowest possible speed to reduce any errors...