# Can not install Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on Acer aspire 4736G through CD/DVD

Tags: 12.04, installation, acer, cd

Nowadays I try install Ubuntu on my laptop through CD,there is a error message I can not resolved,I try many ways ,search the internet,and find some solutions,but it can not help me,who can tell me the answer,thank you

The error message is :
This particular error is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["errno 5 - input/output error" when trying to install Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65830/errno-5-input-output-error-when-trying-to-install-ubuntu)

Answer (score 0):

> This particular error is often due to a faulty CD/DVD disk or drive, or a faulty hard disk. It may help to clean the CD/DVD, to burn the CD/DVD at a lower speed, to clean the CD/DVD drive lens (cleaning kits are often available from electronics suppliers), to check whether the hard disk is old and in need of replacement, or to move the system to a cooler environment.

#### Solutions:

(I'm listing solutions, is not a step-by-step instructions)

1. [Redownload the ISO](https://askubuntu.com/a/338713/169736), [verify the checksums](https://askubuntu.com/q/17764/169736) and [burn again](https://askubuntu.com/q/303083/169736). Then [verify the disk for defects](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck).
2. Use another burner to burn the DVD.
3. Create [a bootable USB](https://askubuntu.com/q/59551/169736).
4. Replace the Hard Disk.
5. Replace the computer.

Comment: Thank you ,I have tried list 1 and 2,but it could not help.i hope I can find the answer.

Comment: @user216616 how about 3? or 4? 5 is the last alternative but I'm sure that either you do that or you will be with the same problem.

Comment: i will have a try,what I am thinking now is some easy methods.